# Lookup a number in comma separated list and return keys separated by comma google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying for so long to figure this out with split, join, vlookup, wild cards etc., but nothing works as expected.
I have 2 google sheet tables, First one with Page ID (over 200 positions), [image]

The second table with data (Blocks! sheet):
[image]

In C column in the first table, I want to have a formula which will search for A2 key through all the comma separated values in **Blocks!A2:A** and return value from **Blocks!C2:C** (if multiple results, separate it with comma). So for example, Im looking for A6 (which is "5") in **Blocks!A2:A**, and the values I am gonna get in C6 are:  "3, 4, 7, 11"

I ended up with the formula:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(join(", ",filter(Blocks!$C$2:$C$24,IFERROR(SEARCH("*"&A8&"*",Blocks!$A$2:$A$24), 0))))` 
But I just noticed a problem with it, meaning if the searched key is 219, it assigns the value from both 219 and 19

Appriciate any help!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZtdbMLBpoda98ETVM3WveGtnCvf3FjB_Iyh-q7mhLuo/edit#gid=0

Comment: To clarify, let's say that you're looking for `1`. Using the formula that you provided, it resulted in `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11`. Is that what you're expecting, or are you wanting `3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10`?

Comment: Yes exactly, the formula provides what you said, and I want 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10

Comment: please share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform).

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZtdbMLBpoda98ETVM3WveGtnCvf3FjB_Iyh-q7mhLuo/edit#gid=48835889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Google Sheets Formula: Find Numbers in Comma-Separated Lists

You may use the following formula to achieve what you'd like to do:

```
=IFERROR(JOIN(", ",FILTER(Blocks!$C$2:$C$12,BYROW(Blocks!$A$2:$A$12,LAMBDA(x,(MATCH(A2,SPLIT(x,","),)))))),"No matches")
```

Instead of using `SEARCH`, use [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) with [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) to get the number to be looked for in the `A2:A` cell of the first sheet. The formula then searches for the value in the list on the `Blocks` sheet and returns the `Block ID` of where it located the number. If the number is not found in the list, it will say `No matches`. Just drag the formula down, depending on the number of items the sheet currently has.

##### OUTPUT

[image]

##### REFERENCES

- [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718)
- [BYROW function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930)

Comment: @beko I would recommend that in the future, instead of just posting pictures of your data, you can also create [`Tables`](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) so that other community members can easily copy and paste them on their own spreadsheets.

Comment: As @[`Argyll`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181104) has stated, this is likely `a well-formulated question`, it's just that it doesn't have `text-based examples`, which is why the solution they've provided consists of `concepts only`. You can also [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) if you're having trouble creating tables as suggested by @[`z..`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17887301).

Comment: Hey Guys, sorry, I just created a sample document and updated the question with the link!

Comment: Match and Split did the trick! ohh wow, thanks for helping!

Comment: I'm happy to hear that your issue's been resolved!

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the problem as having two parts: 1) a formula for single-cell output that parses through `'Blocks'!`, e.g. for `A2`, `C2` alone; 2) an additional layer that applies part 1) through all of `A2:A`.

There are many ways to achieve part 1). Using `find`, `arrayformula` and the aggregating results with `join` only involve built-in formulas without array functions. So that is preferable. For example,

```js
=join(", ",
      filter(Blocks!B2:B,
            arrayformula(iferror(find(A2&",",Blocks!A2:A&","),false))))
```

The trick here is to append `Blocks!A2:A` with `,` and therefore avoiding to use `or` within `arrayformula`. The two are *not* compatible. With this trick, we are able to stay within built-in functions and `arrayformula`.

From part 1), since we have a single cell reference alongside a range reference when using `find`, and we also used a layer of `filter`, there is no way to apply the formula to a range with only built-in functions and `arrayformula` anymore.

Thus, for part 2), you will need to use an array function to apply the formula to all of `A2:A`, for example, with `map`, as follows.

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(c,if(isblank(c),,
 join(", ",filter(Blocks!B2:B,arrayformula(iferror(find(c&",",Blocks!A2:A&","),false)))))))
```

Comment: note that you don't need ARRAYFORMULA, since FILTER is already an array-enabling function.

Comment: @z..: True. And `false` is probably not needed in `iferror()` either. As a rule, I do not test solutions to questions without text-based examples. For a well-formulated question, I'd still answer, but with concepts only. So the answer above contains just concepts -- subcomponents of formulas are implicitly separate parts if we want to be more verbose. The answer is not an end-to-end solution.